# CSS transition not applying correctly?

Tags: css, stylus

In my navigation menu, the transition on the main menu buttons is functioning correctly. I am using Stylus.

Here is the codepen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVqydm

```
header nav ul li
    display inline-block
    position relative

    padding 13px
    font-weight normal

    transition: all 0.4s // Transform here

header nav > ul > li
    font-family "Arial"
    font-weight bold
    font-size 1em

header nav ul li:hover
    background-color lighten(_grey, 50%)
```

This code causes the transition to occur on hover, but I also want the sub list that shows upon hovering over the li to transition in as well. I have it set up to do this, but I must be doing it incorrectly.

The HTML structure is the very typical

```
ul
    li
        a
        ul
            li
                a
```

The follow code is for the sub lists, but it does no transition.

```
header nav ul li ul
    padding 0
    position absolute
    top 40px
    min-width 200px
    display none
    opacity 0
    visibility hidden

    transition all 0.4s

header nav ul li:hover ul
    display block
    opacity 1
    visibility visible
```

How would I get the transition also to apply to the sub list when hovering over the top li.

Comment: Could you provide some code in http://jsfiddle.net ??

Comment: Does that type of syntax work for CSS? Without curly brackets, colons, and semicolons?

Comment: @BenAdamsky: That's Stylus code (pre-processor)

Comment: I am using Stylus and Jade. I cannot provide a jsfiddle because of that. Here is the relevant Stylus code. https://gist.github.com/Connorelsea/43eb16447531b9d62deb

Comment: @Connorelsea: You could use both in CodePen if I remember right :)

Comment: What is wrong with my question. Being downvoted?

Comment: Here is the codepen. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVqydm

Comment: Thanks Harry. Should I use opacity instead or something?

Comment: Yeah I got the animation working by moving display, but can't figure out how to make them not take up space, which is causing them to pop up when not hovering over the ul, etc. Can you demonstrate the height transition? Thank you.

Comment: @Connorelsea: Sorry, [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) actually seems to be a transitionable property. I had got it wrong and it was only the `display` and so Karl's answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Stylus, but I think it's the `display none` that's causing the issue. Removing that seems to have fixed it at this [forked pen](http://codepen.io/KBD/pen/XbORqa)

```
header nav ul li ul
    padding 0
    position absolute
    top 40px
    min-width 200px
    opacity 0
    visibility hidden

    transition all 0.4s
```